# Formatar número de um input

Tags: php, javascript, formatação, number-format

Tenho um sistema que calcula a média dos campos e em seguida executa o javascript abaixo, só que o resultado sai assim 0.222048 e o correto seria 222.048, como fazer essa conversão?

```
<script>
     function calcularMediam3etes() {
        var m1 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['mediaQ_lsE'].value;
        var mqm3 = (m1 * 86.400)/1000;
        document.forms['formMediasETEs']['mediaQm3E'].value = mqm3;
    }
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Comment: Já experimentaste a não dividir por mil?

Comment: O problema é que o calculo tem que ser dividido por mil, a fórmula é N * 86.400 / 1000. 
Com esse calculo descobrimos a vazão diária por metro cubico, não tem como tirar. ;(

Comment: Se a formula está correta por que o resultado estaria errado? Imagino que a divisão por mil faz o numero resultante ter como unidade o metro cúbico. Sem a divisão a unidade seria litros. Pra min parece uma questão de converter entre unidades de medidas.  Com base no exemplo que você deu.

Comment: Pq o resultado sai assim 0.222048 e o correto seria 222.048, no excel, calculadora ou qualquer outro sai normal.. só no código que sai fora do formato que preciso.
Teria alguma ideia pra ajudar? Já tirei a divisão / 1000, mas tb não resolveu por causa do ponto das casas decimais.

Comment: Talvez o resultado seja suposto então sair em dm cubico